# Power supplies in parallel

Tags: power-supply

Can you connect a Pyramid PS36KX 12-15V 32A DC Power Supply in parallel with a Tripp-lite PR 25 to get more amperage for my Ham Shack

Please follow this link and please let me know if this is possible using this method

https://www.keysight.com/main/editorial.jspx%3Fcc%3DUS%26lc%3Deng%26ckey%3D520808%26nid%3D-11143.0.00%26id%3D520808

Comment: Most probably not.

Comment: Hi, David. Standard practice is to include links to the datasheets for each item in your post. You can [edit] them in. What's your power-up sequence going to be?

Comment: What do the manuals say about it? Power supplies can rarely be paralleled unless they specifically support it.

Comment: Will see what I can find THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.  Power supplies designed for paralleling generally have a separate signal wire that goes between the (usually identical) units to coordinate output voltages and so forth.  If there is no communication between the units, one of them will end up trying to force current into the other one due to voltage differences.  Even if you have them adjusted to identical voltages at no load, they will droop at different rates as you draw more current and there you are.

Answer (score 0):

Only two identical, fixed-voltage power supplies, which have the provision to do so, may be connected in parallel.

There is no way one could parallel two disparate supplies, one being rated 12-15V 32A and the other 13.8V 25A.